# read.csv2 gives all the data in one column

Tags: r, csv, bioinformatics

I am trying to read a csv file, I tired both `read.csv` and `read.csv2` and tried all `sep` options but the data frame is all in one column and isn't organized.
this is my code :

```
disease_type <- read.csv2("C:/Documents/Cancer_Bioinformatics/disease_type.csv")
head(disease_type)
```

this is the result

```
                                                                                 V1
1 cases.submitter_id;"diagnoses.primary_diagnosis";"diagnoses.classification_of_tumor",
2                                                 ad10006;"Carcinoma, NOS";"metastasis"
3                                            ad10012;"Lobular carcinoma, NOS";"primary"
4                                  ad10013;"Infiltrating duct carcinoma, NOS";"primary"
5                                  ad10014;"Infiltrating duct carcinoma, NOS";"primary"
6                                  ad10020;"Infiltrating duct carcinoma, NOS";"primary"
```

this is a snip of the original csv file I'm trying to read:

[image]

what can be done ?

this is a snip of the file opened with notepad:

[image]

Comment: Is your delimiter `;` i.e. `sep=";"` and `fill = TRUE`

Comment: looks at first glance like it should work. Can you post a link to the file itself, or cut-and-paste the text of the first few lines of the file (i.e. open the CSV file in a text editor)?

Comment: I added a snip of the original file, perhaps the flaw is in the file it self ?

Comment: It is difficult to see the file contents after it is opened in Excel, which does some conversion during opening. Better to open in a text editor, copy and paste in some lines, or even show an image of how it looks in the text editor.

Comment: I added another picture please check it out, my problem still haven't been solved